# Powershell GUI Issues

Tags: powershell

I know the code I have isn't quite correct in terms of the loop, at the ,moment, once I click the start button,  thew window freezes and the form/buttons do not respond to any input, which I know is due to the infinite do while loop. This is my first Powershell GUI script and I have tried to find answers but so far unsuccessful.
I want the code to keep running in the form but allow the form to be movable and the stop button t close the GUI/script.

Here is an example of the code:

```
        Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
        Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
        #Form + Properties
        $main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $main_form.TopMost = $True
        $main_form.Text ='Techs'
        $main_form.Width = 300
        $main_form.Height = 450
        $main_form.AutoSize = $true
        
        #Textbox1 + Properties
        $TextBox1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $TextBox1.BackColor = "Black"
        $TextBox1.multiline = $true
        $TextBox1.width = 295
        $TextBox1.height = 195
        $TextBox1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(05,30)
        $TextBox1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $main_form.Controls.Add($Textbox1)
        
        #Textbox2 + Properties
        $TextBox2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $TextBox2.BackColor = "Black"
        $TextBox2.multiline = $true
        $TextBox2.width = 295
        $TextBox2.height = 195
        $TextBox2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(05,225)
        $TextBox2.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $main_form.Controls.Add($Textbox2)
        
        #Start Button + Properties
        $buttonStart = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
        $buttonStart.text = "Start"
        $buttonStart.Size = '80,20'
        $buttonStart.location = '05, 05'
        $buttonStart.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $main_form.Controls.Add($buttonStart)
        
        #Stop Button + Properties
        $buttonStop = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
        $buttonStop.text = "Stop"
        $buttonStop.Size = '80,20'
    $buttonStop.location = '90, 05'

$buttonStop.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$main_form.Controls.Add($buttonStop)

cls
$x=1
$TechArray = "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
$url = "https://website/api/v3/techs/"
$tech_key = @{ 'authtoken' = '12345678-12AB-12AB-1111-1111'}

$buttonStart.Add_Click({
Do {
 
  $TextBox1.Text=""
  $TextBox2.Text=""
  foreach ($Tech in $TechArray) {
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url$Tech -Method get -Headers $tech_Key
  if ($response.tech.is_online -eq "1") 
    {
          $TextBox1.ForeColor = "Green"
          $TextBox1.AppendText("`n`n Online - " + $response.tech.login_name + "`n`n")
 
    }
  else 
    {
          $TextBox2.ForeColor = "Red"
          $TextBox2.AppendText("`n`n Offline - " + $response.tech.login_name + "`n`n")
         
    }

 }
  
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

}

while ($x -ne 0)
})

$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the fetching of the web call from your UI thread.
This means you need to create a separate thread to execute this as a background task.

In Powershell (Core) 7+ there is this cmdLet: `Start-ThreadJob`, but there is also a port of this in Powershell 5.1, which you can download from:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob/2.0.3

As a sample proof of concept instead of this, which blocks the UI thread:

```
$buttonStart.Add_Click({
  Write-Host "Hi" 
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Try this one and you'll see that the window does not freeze anymore:

```
$buttonStart.Add_Click({
  Start-ThreadJob -StreamingHost $Host -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host "Hi"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
  } 
})
```